# Shorter way to define custom JavaScript exceptions?

Tags: javascript, custom-exceptions

I'm defining custom JavaScript exceptions like the code below. Is this proper? Isn't there a shorter way?

```
function InvalidModuleError(moduleName) {
    TypeError.apply(this);
    this.message = "module '" + moduleName + "' doesn't export any definitions";
    this.name = 'InvalidModuleError';
};

InvalidModuleError.prototype = Object.create(TypeError.prototype);


function DuplicateModuleError(moduleName) {
    TypeError.apply(this);
    this.message = "module '" + moduleName + "' is already defined";
    this.name = 'DuplicateModuleError';
};

DuplicateModuleError.prototype = Object.create(TypeError.prototype);
```

**Edit:** Eventually, after Oriol's suggestion, I've made a function that generates exceptions and looks like this:

```
function makeException(parentObject, parentClass, name, message) {
    var shortName = name.split('.');
    shortName = shortName[shortName.length - 1];
    parentObject[shortName] = function() {
        this.message = (typeof message === 'function') ? message.apply(null, arguments) : message;
    };
    parentObject[shortName].prototype = Object.create(parentClass.prototype, {'name': {'value': name}});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be simplified a bit:

```
function InvalidModuleError(moduleName) {
    this.message = "module '" + moduleName + "' doesn't export any definitions";
}
InvalidModuleError.prototype = new Error();
InvalidModuleError.prototype.name = 'InvalidModuleError';

function DuplicateModuleError(moduleName) {
    this.message = "module '" + moduleName + "' is already defined";
}
DuplicateModuleError.prototype = new Error();
DuplicateModuleError.prototype.name = 'DuplicateModuleError';
```

But if you want to have lots of custom exceptions, better use

```
function newModuleError(errorName, message) {
    var moduleError = function(moduleName) {
        this.message = message.replace('%s', moduleName);
    };
    moduleError.prototype = new Error();
    moduleError.prototype.name = errorName;
    return moduleError; 
};

var InvalidModuleError = newModuleError('InvalidModuleError', "module '%s' doesn't export any definitions"),
    DuplicateModuleError = newModuleError('DuplicateModuleError', "module '%s' is already defined");
```

To throw them:

```
throw new InvalidModuleError("moduleName1");
throw new DuplicateModuleError("moduleName2");
```

Comment: I'm defining exceptions. It seems, that without prototype inheritance (`MyException.prototype = Object.create(BaseException.prototype);`) exceptions are not printed in browser's console properly (maybe I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: @PythonFanboy I have added a `toString` method to display it well.

Comment: @PythonFanboy I have updated it to throw real errors instead of objects with `.toString`